# How to change domain.com/#!/url to domain.com/url

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-crawler

I would like to know, is it possible to change links structure from domain.com/#!/home to domain.com/home

I tried using htaccess but it doesn't change anything. I was looking for information on the Internet and found out that it is calling "ajax crawling". Unfortunately I have not found how to remove/disable/redirect.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the URL fragment (everything after the `#`) using mod_rewrite or an htaccess file. These fragments are **never sent to the server** so anything on the server side is unable to access them. While you can redirect the browser to a URL *with* a fragment, you'll never be able to detect whether a fragment exists.

You'll need to do the redirect using Javascript on the browser's end. Check for the fragment and redirect the browser to a URL in the form of `domain.com/url`.